Percent encoding shouldn't show after the deeplink is executed using Swift for iOS
I've the following string (please pay attention the string has "&")
let text = "By submitting, I confirm that I am an American, above 18 yrs of age & residing in America. I have read & agree to American Bank. I also agree to receive calls, SMS & WhatsApp messages from American Bank"

This is how I encode the string:
let encodedTxt = text.removingPercentEncoding?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""

For the sake of working example, I will send this string to Bear app. This is how I create the deeplink URL:
var components = URLComponents(string: "bear://x-callback-url/create")!
            components.queryItems = [
                URLQueryItem(name: "title", value: "Title),
                URLQueryItem(name: "text", value: encodedTxt),
                URLQueryItem(name: "x-success", value: "myapp://bear-note-created")
            ]

This is the output of the url components
bear://x-callback-url/create?title=\(title)&text=\(encodedTxt)&x-success=myapp://bear-note-created

When the above link is executed, I see the output is still have the encoding in the Bear app
By%20submitting,%20I%20confirm%20that%20I%20am%20an%20American,%20above%2018%20yrs%20of%20age%20&%20residing%20in%20America.%20I%20have%20read%20&%20agree%20to%20American%20Bank%20Privacy%20Policy.%20I%20also%20agree%20to%20receive%20calls,%20SMS%20&%20WhatsApp%20messages%20from%20American%20Bank

Expected result must be without percent encoding in the output.
Any help is highly appreciated.

URLQueryItem(name: "text", value: encodedTxt) -> URLQueryItem(name: "text", value: text) should be enough

@Larme I've tried already that then when the deeplink is exected it returns value up until anything before "&"

If you test with var components = URLComponents(string: "bear://x/create")!; components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "key1", value: "text & this1"), URLQueryItem(name: "key2", value: "text & this2".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)]; print(components.url!.absoluteString) you'll see that URLQueryItem should already percent escape the needed value, so you are doing double percent escape and I guess that Bear doesn't expect this behavior...

Could you replace text with "By submitting, I ... & blablabla", hardcode the other Title value and print components.url.asboluteString and share it? That's strange that the decoding fails on their end.

I have turned your code fragments into a working test and reduced the size of the text to make it more readable.
import Foundation

let text = "age & residing"
let encodedTxt = text.removingPercentEncoding?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
print(encodedTxt)

var components = URLComponents(string: "bear://x-callback-url/create")!
components.queryItems = [
                URLQueryItem(name: "title", value: "Title"),
                URLQueryItem(name: "text", value: encodedTxt),
                URLQueryItem(name: "x-success", value: "myapp://bear-note-created")
            ]
print("\n1 Components:")
print(components.string!)

components.queryItems = [
                URLQueryItem(name: "title", value: "Title"),
                URLQueryItem(name: "text", value: text),
                URLQueryItem(name: "x-success", value: "myapp://bear-note-created")
            ]
print("\n2 Components:")
print(components.string!)


This is the output I get:
age%20&%20residing

1 Components:
bear://x-callback-url/create?title=Title&text=age%2520%26%2520residing&x-success=myapp://bear-note-created

2 Components:
bear://x-callback-url/create?title=Title&text=age%20%26%20residing&x-success=myapp://bear-note-created

Your encoding encodes the spaces but omits the & because of .urlQueryAllowed. Then the creation of a URLQueryItem does a second encoding but does not omit the & (line below 1 Components:). The most important thing to note is that all of the % symbols have been changed to %25 which is the correct percent encoding if you want a literal % in your string.
The app that receives the URL will do one pass of percent decoding the query. It will decode the %25s to % and it will decode the %26 to &. These are the only percent encoded characters it will see. At this point, it will not recognise the percent encoded spaces because it looks like a percent encoded % with the literal number 20 after it.
If you are using URLQueryItem you do not need to do your own percent encoding at all. Just feed in the unencoded string. This can be seen from the second assignment of queryItems above. The output (below 2 Components:)is exactly what you need to transmit your string as a query item.
